# Removing rows based on Duplicates within Column R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe which contains entries identified by an application number "Apno". There are many duplicates within the dataframe where the majority of info is the same but one or two pieces differ slightly making a straight unique() command not applicable for my purposes. The good thing is rows with the same value for Apno refer to the same thing and it doesnt really matter which entry is kept. I need only unique apno's while retaining the other data. Example :

```
Apno  Name   Location

123   Gary   New York
124   Larry  Boston
123   Garry  NYC
155   Jerry  San Francisco
122   Mary   Chicago
123   Gari   NY
124   Lary   Bos.
```

After filtering on Apno:

```
Apno  Name   Location

123   Gary   New York
124   Larry  Boston
155   Jerry  San Francisco
122   Mary   Chicago
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Apno) %>%
    slice(1L)
```

Or a `base R` option would be

```
df1[!duplicated(df1$Apno),]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Apno = c(123L, 124L, 123L, 155L, 122L, 123L, 124L
 ), Name = c("Gary", "Larry", "Garry", "Jerry", "Mary", "Gari", 
"Lary"), Location = c("New York", "Boston", "NYC", "San Francisco", 
"Chicago", "NY", "Bos.")), .Names = c("Apno", "Name", "Location"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```